# get textarea value from dynamic dom on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, keypress

I'am trying to get the value from a dynamic added dom elements, with inspiration from this answer:

[Jquery .keypress on a dynamically added input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983204/jquery-keypress-on-a-dynamically-added-input)

My code:

```
var commentbox = $('<div class=\"span6\"><textarea rows=\"1\" data-replyparent=\"'+replyparentid+'\" class="replytocomment" id=\"'+commentboxid+'\" style=\"display:none;\"></textarea></div>')
    .keypress (function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == 13) {
            console.log("it seems to work: "+ $(this).val());


            $.ajax({
                url: '/add/comment',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: id,
                    parent: replyparentid,
                    comment: comment
                },
                success: function(){
                }
            });
        }
    })
    .insertAfter(placeholder)
;
//then insert the emojionearea after the placeholder
//$(commentbox).insertAfter(placeholder);
$('.replytocomment').emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom",
    filtersPosition: "bottom",
    tonesStyle: "bullet"
});
```

I can't figure out how to get the value from the textarea on keycode 13, how is that possible, when using it "inline".

In the console I only get "it seems to work" but not the value form the textarea.

If I update the var commentbox, to have something in the textarea, like this:

```
var commentbox = $('<div class=\"span6\"><textarea rows=\"1\" data-replyparent=\"'+replyparentid+'\" class="replytocomment" id=\"'+commentboxid+'\" style=\"display:none;\">TESTING</textarea></div>')
```

It works with: $(this).find('textarea').val()

So I guess it might have something to do with the listener?
Seems a bit strange though, because when I log the entire element like this: console.log($(this).find('textarea'));
To the console, it shows the correct an updated value in the valuefield.

Best regards.

Comment: Already Solved, Jquery Key Press Event.
[Please check the below link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25399566/jquery-key-press-event-on-textarea)

Answer (score 2):

The event is set on the wrapping `div`, not the `textarea`, so `this` inside the `eventhandler` is the `div`. Use `$(this).find('textarea').val()` to get the value from the `textarea`.

Comment: console.log("it seems to work: "+  $(this).find('textarea').val());
Prints nothing. $(this).find('textarea'). prints: it seems to work: [object Object]

Comment: Try `e.target` instead of `this`. Any change?

Comment: $(e.target).find('textarea') prints: it seems to work: [object Object]

Comment: I would try to console `$(this).find('textarea').attr('id')` and `$(this).find('textarea').data('replyparent')`. Do you get the data of the `textarea`?

Comment: It prints: "8003cddf-b09d-f0e0-8754-22f2807e0515" and "1" which is expected as its the correct id's

Comment: But it still doesn't get the `val()` of the `textarea`? what if you use javascript `.value` - `$(this).find('textarea')[0].value`?

Comment: No it dosen't. The javascript method dosen't print anything. After the .insertAfter(), I call this function. I don't know if that has anything to do with it? (see updated question.)